# Angularjs routing issue, controller not loading

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have 4 files:

- index.html
- logic.js
- controller.js
- homepage.html

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="sample">
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>    
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="logic.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**logic.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('sample',[]);
    myapp.config(function($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {   
                    controller:homepageCtrl,
                    templateUrl:'homepage.html'             
            });
    });
```

**controller.js**

```
function homepageCtrl($scope){
        $scope.name = "ROHIT";}
```

**homepage.html**

```
{{name}}
```

homepage.html is loading and being displayed correctly by the route but the controller is not being called here when homepage.html is loaded into index.html.

Kindly help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked console to see if there was an error? If it didn't find your controller then that would explain why it shows up like that.

Comment: I have same issue the big problem is that no error at console

Answer (score 2):

You didn't defined controller in HTML.

Add this line

```
<div ng-controller = "homepageCtrl">
```

Suppose it should be in `homepage.html`:

```
<div ng-controller = "homepageCtrl">
   {{name}}
</div>
```

In addition, wrap your controller name with `'` `logic.js`

**[EDIT]**

Add `$inject` to routeProvider:

```
myapp.config(["$routeProvider",
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'homepage.html', 
            controller: 'homepageCtrl'
        });
}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks.But this is not necessary right as the routing takes care of this in logic.js . I did try it with this as well , but to no avail.

Comment: @rohit see my edit, maybe you didn't `$inject`? I changed a bit your config

Comment: I've found the issue,thanks. The $inject is not required and we dont need to specify the controller name too 

<div ng-controller = "homepageCtrl"> 

I actually had a couple of extra things in  {{ }} that i didn't put up ,angular had some issues parsing it.It worked when i removed it.

Comment: i happened to have some mustache code with #,/ in the {{ }} which angular couldn't parse and hence it didn't display {{name}} too even though {{name}} was not enclosed with any of the mustache code

Comment: this is wrong how can you say to define controller in html when rohit is defining controller in routeProvider...defining controller in both the places is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Controller name must be pass to $routeProvider as a string :

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {   
                    controller:'homepageCtrl',
                    templateUrl:'homepage.html'             
            });
```

Comment: Thanks but i have already tried this with the quotes    controller:'homepageCtrl'  but its not working.

Comment: @rohit : OK, How do you add your controller to angular ?