# dynamic header/menu in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-include

While transitioning an existing angular site, I encountered an annoying problem. The initial symptom was that a certain controller was not running it's initialize function immediately following the login. I logged and I tracked, and eventually I realized it was a design flaw of the page. Essentially, index.html contains a `<header>`, `<ng-view>`, and `<footer>`. There are a couple of `ng-if` attributes that live in the header that I want to evaluate after the login, but since the view is the only thing that is reloaded, it was not reinitializing the header controller, and thus not updating the ng-if values.

Then I was reminded of ngInclude, which seems like the perfect solution, until I got it hooked up and realize that doesn't work either. It loads the template the first time, and doesn't reinitialize when the view changes. So then I got the bright idea of passing the HeaderController to another controller or service, and controlling this one stubborn boolean value through a proxy of sorts. That also didn't work. Then I tried putting a function and a boolean into another service, and mirroring that property in the header controller, but thus far I have not gotten this working.

I have done plenty of research about multiple views in the index, and so far I hear a lot about this ui-router, but I'm still not convinced that is the way I want to go. It does not seem to be a simple solution. I have not tried putting the ng-include into the templates yet either, because then I feel like that is going back in time to when we had to update 100 pages every time we changed the menu.

I lost a whole day to this. If anyone could tell me how to trigger the evaluation of this one property in my header controller which I would like to live outside the other templates, please let me know!

Comment: Is it a routing issue like in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914183/angularjs-routing-issue-controller-not-loading ?

Comment: @ralfhtp the header does not get its own route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you need to know in your `HeaderController` when the view has reloaded. There's a number of ways of doing this but the easier and maybe the more correct in this particular case is with an event.

So when you are refreshing the view you just do this, let's say you need the new value of `ob1` and `ob2` variables.

```
// ViewController
$rootScope.$emit('viewRefresh', {ob1: 'newvalue1', ob2: 'newvalue2'});
```

And in your `HeaderController` you need to listen for that event, and set on your $scope the new values for those attrs (if you're not using `controller as` syntax).

```
// HeaderController
$rootScope.$on('viewRefresh', function onRefresh(event, data) {
    $scope.ob1 = data.ob1;
    $scope.ob2 = data.ob2;
})
```

**Another Solution**
Sharing a Promise through a Service (using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q))

```
function HeaderService($q) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    return {
        getPromise: function() {return defer.promise},
        notify: function(data) {defer.notify(data)}
    }
}

function HeaderController(HeaderService) {
    var vm = this;
    HeaderService.getPromise().then(function(data) {
        vm.ob1 = data.ob1;
        vm.ob2 = data.ob2;
    })
}


function ViewController(HeaderService) {
    var data =  {ob1: 'newvalue1', ob2: 'newvalue2'};
    HeaderService.notify(data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am indeed using controllerAs syntax, and I generally try to avoid doing too much with $rootScope. If this was your website and you had all the time in the world, is that how you would fix this? If not, would you share your ideal solution here? @Bolza

Comment: Also, for this solution, are you recommending I put this into all of my view templates?

Comment: Honestly if you don't have many cases like this, i believe messing with the rootScope is fine. Especially when it's about very important components used everywhere in the website like the Header.
Another solution could be creating a service that returns a promise, i'm updating the answer with this.

Comment: You might be right about it being safe to update $rootScope for a menu that is fundamentally global, but for the sake of exploring all options, what do you think about the idea of using a directive? I have not written a lot of directives, but I know it can be associated with a template and is intended for DOM manipulation, which is what this problem represents. @Bolza

Comment: Even if you use a directive you'll still need a way to comunicate between some controller that updates the data and your directive that shows those data. What do you think of using a promise and a service as i suggested in the second part of the answer?

Comment: That is actually very close to what I was trying earlier. I did not come up with the idea of converting the controller to a service, nor did I come up with returning a promise. It's pretty interesting. I am at the end of my rope with this today, but will try your ideas tomorrow and update this thread when I do. Thank you so much for your feedback. I wish Angular would give us multiple views already!

Comment: If you want multiple view you have to use uiRouter but it doesnt address this specifc problem. Communication between components is done by services or events. Just a word of advice, if you are making an app that is going to be medium/big go for uiRouter now because you'll probably need it anyway and it will be painful to implement it later on in the development.

Comment: I hear you on that. It is not a big app, thankfully. After thinking about it for 24 hours I decided to make a header service. I like the idea that it can then be handled in the $route.resolve() along with authentication. You were a big help, so thank you.

Comment: Aw man. That didn't work either, because there is no route for the header! D'oh! Your solution, after consideration, is more work than just putting an ng-include within the ng-view. This way every view gets a separate ng-include for the header, body, and footer, and each one will resolve its own dependencies which are unrelated to the route itself when the view is changed.